# MySQL Sum positive and negative - calculate the exact total from money transactions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table full of transactions. The transactions contain negative numbers from people returning items. I would like to add up all the amount field while also subtracting the negative values of returns from the total. How can I do this and output it out?
Currently the best I can do is get:

```
  SELECT SUM(amount) 
  FROM outputaddition 
  GROUP by SIGN(amount);
```

But this only puts positive and negative in the same column.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and expected result for it please?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
SELECT personId,SUM(CASE WHEN amount<0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as NegativeTotal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN amount>=0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as PostiveTotal
FROM outputaddition
GROUP BY personID
```

If you want single column

```
SELECT personId,SUM(amount) as Total
FROM outputaddition
GROUP BY personID
```

Comment: Thanks but that just separates the two values into different columns... how do i perform the subtraction of negative from positive from this result

Comment: the negative sign when added will subtract from total..so need to bother about it , just pass all the values to SUM aggregate function

Comment: are you sure about that??

Comment: SURE DID, THANK YOU HASAN

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  as ActualTotal
    ,Sum(Case When amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) totalOfPositiveOnly
  FROM outputaddition
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your answer is ambiguous; we're not sure exactly what you're asking.

Most simply, if "subtracting the negative values" means you just want to ignore the negative returns:

select sum(amount)
where amount > 0;

Comment: basically i have a lot of totals in a colunm but i want to get he end result, ie the pure profit from it so i need to subtract any negative values form my totals

Comment: ok, so if positive amount adds to the total, and negative amount subtracts from the total, then just add everything up: select sum(amount) from...;